# Check file exists in variable

Tags: php

Quite a simple one this I imagine.

I'm submitting a form with text and images.

I validate the text by checking the variable length !=0 etc.

I need an effective way to check if the variable that should have a file within does.

This is the code so far...

```
if(!$afterphoto){
    $form->setError($field, "After photo not entered");
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, what would be a better checker?

Thanks.

Comment: you appear to be using some sort of library or framework since you ask $form. What is $form? Please provide more context/code

Comment: That's just a form object that sets errors and returns them etc. It's the if statement I'm asking about. The variable $afterphoto is set by $_FILES['afterphoto']...how do I check that there is something in the variable?

Comment: If you var_dump($_FILES['afterphoto']) you'll see that there is an attribute for the temporarily stored, uploaded file. I guess that's the information you use to upload it anyway right? So check if that tmp file is valid using the php function file_exists http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Also do read this for further information http://de1.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I do have another function I use after validating the form that uses those functions but I was just wondering if there was a way to check the variable itself has a file within but it doesn't appear so. I'll have to change the order of the code around a bit! Cheers dude.

Comment: try to check for `$_FILES['afterphoto']['tmp_name']` with file_exists. That should "do the trick".

Comment: So $afterphoto['tmp'name'] should do the same then? I pass $_FILES['afterphoto'] into $afterphoto? That doesn't seem to be doing the trick!

Comment: what's the outcome of file_exists on that? What's the content of $_FILES? what's the content of $afterphoto? Those are the questions that should lead you to the right solution for you. Also ... od RTFM as told ;-)

Comment: Been through the manual and found a solution! Check - $afterphoto['error'] != 0 - I'll answer the question when I can!

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this was to use the following code to check that there were no errors and the file was uploaded:

```
$afterphoto['error'] != 0
```